# How to I convert discrete data into interval in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have input data below. And I would like to convert this data into output data. I am using python language and numpy and pandas. Please help me out to solve it.

**Input data:**

```
        Product                 year    Total sale
    0   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2000    63131
    1   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2001    47453
    2   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2002    52839
    3   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2003    64041
    4   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2004    66825
    5   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2005    64335
    6   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2006    63778
    7   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2007    68938
    8   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2008    68935
    9   Aviation Turbine Fuel   2009    82631
    10  Aviation Turbine Fuel   2010    101314
    11  Aviation Turbine Fuel   2011    109808
    12  Aviation Turbine Fuel   2012    115786
    13  Aviation Turbine Fuel   2013    123527
    14  Aviation Turbine Fuel   2014    139404
```

This is the output I wanted to print.

**Output:**

```
Product                 Year        Avg
Aviation Turbine Fuel   2010-2014   117967.8
Aviation Turbine Fuel   2005-2009   69723.4
Aviation Turbine Fuel   2000-2004   58857.8
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far

Comment: I am new to python. I searched on google and could not find any thing related to this. I tried by using function but could not get a clue. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) and [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
bins=[1999,2004,2009,2014]
labels=['2000-2004','2005-2009','2010-2014']
df['Year']=pd.cut(df.year,bins,labels=labels)
print(df.groupby('Year',as_index=False).agg({'Product':'first','Total sale':'mean'}))
```

Output:

```
        Year                Product  Total sale
0  2000-2004  Aviation Turbine Fuel     58857.8
1  2005-2009  Aviation Turbine Fuel     69723.4
2  2010-2014  Aviation Turbine Fuel    117967.8
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try :)